# Couldn't find User without an ID with one_to_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails, and having a problem with nested routes.

I have users, each with one profile in a separate model. Attempting to access a user profile

> /users/1/profile

produces the error:

> Couldn't find User without an ID

The request parameters show:

> {"user_id"=>"1"}

There have been questions similar to this asked, but can't find a solution to this.

Routes:

```
resources :users do
  resource :profile
end
```

Profile controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user_profile = User.find(params[:id]).profile
  end
end
```

From User model:

```
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
before_create :build_profile
```

From Profile model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

I guess that `User.find(params[:id]).profile` is where I'm going wrong. I changed the `find(params[:id])` to `first`, which successfully returns the first user's profile.

Would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The user id will come in as `params[:user_id]`. Check your logs for the parameters being passed and interpreted. `params[:id]` isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your route design, which should be no more complex than that for a simple profile showing.

But there are some problems:

1. The route in routes.rb should be

   ```
   resources :user do
     member do
       get 'profile'
     end
   end
   ```

   This will allow `user/1/profile` route
2. The `profile` method should be in UsersController instead of a profile controller, according to above routing. (And a profile controller is not necessary in this case)

   ```
   class UsersController < ApplictionController
     def profile
       user = User.find(params[:id])
       @profile = user.profile
     end
   end
   ```